# Copy some entries from one server database to other server database using asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

We are doing some CRUD operation in DEV environment and data is saved in database. For other environments(like Staging/Prod) we want to copy those records from DEV database and paste to Staging/Prod when required using asp.net MVC. Is it possible? Could you please suggest some pathway in order to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using a linked server:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15

This involves creating a link between one database server and another (they must be able to see each other on the network). You can then reference the linked server like this:

```
INSERT INTO [LinkedServerName].[Database].[dbo].[Table] (......
```

Alternatively you could use a paid for tool like SSMS tools which can generate insert statements on a per table basis: https://www.ssmstoolspack.com/

Comment: I achieved this by using enums . I added multiple edmx file in global layer(Class libraries) and through switch cases in controller